# harmonic ratio of every four points in conformal mapping

Tags: conformal-geometry

i know the concept of harmonic functions or the conformal mapping and also i know some characteristics of the conformal mapping( i think ). i have already faced a theorem: "the conformal mapping keeps the harmonic ratio of every four points as a constant value." now, i ask you if you know the proof of it.
the mathematical form:
((z1-z2)/(z1-z4)) / ((z3-z2)/(z3-z4)) = ((w1-w2)/(w1-w4)) / ((w3-w2)/(w3-w4)) 
i admit that almost i have no idea for the proof.
i thank you very much, if you help me.

Comment: Where did you find such a "theorem"?

Comment: @studiosus you can find it in wiki too. i think it was cross ratio. but i remember that i didn't understand that.

Comment: Well, there are conformal mappings which are not Moebius/linear fractional. They do not preserve the cross ratio.

Answer (score 0):

thank you every one. I have found my answer, lol! it was not hard but i got afraid at first. remember mobius mapping. we have from it:
wi - wj = ((ad-bc)(zi-zj))/((czi+d)(czj+d)) . now if you write this for all the terms in the left side, you will earn the right side. thanks